# CIImage with float RGB data(no alpha)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-image

I'm struggling to display properly float RGB HDR data, i use this code ti create CIImage, but displayed image looks gradated
Here is my code, I really appreciate any suggestions

```
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] 
                    initWithBitmapDataPlanes:(unsigned char **)&hdr_ctxt.img
                    pixelsWide:hdr_ctxt.width
                    pixelsHigh:hdr_ctxt.height
                    bitsPerSample:32
                    samplesPerPixel:hdr_ctxt.channels
                    hasAlpha:NO
                    isPlanar:NO
colorSpaceName:hdr_ctxt.channels == 1?NSDeviceWhiteColorSpace:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
                    bitmapFormat:NSFloatingPointSamplesBitmapFormat
                    bytesPerRow:0
                    bitsPerPixel:0] autorelease];
    ciImageHdr = [[[CIImage alloc] initWithBitmapImageRep:bitmapRep] autorelease];
```

Comment: NSData *tiff = [bitmapRep TIFFRepresentation];               ciImageHdr = [[[CIImage alloc] initWithData:tiff]autorelease];      do the magic...